# Getting errors while trying some condition on an array

Tags: typescript

Trying to check if an array has some values and display it once in `typescript`

```
const items = products?.reduce((prev: any, current) => {
  if (!current?.data()?.drinkName in prev) {
    prev[current?.data()?.category] = [];
  }
   prev[current?.data()?.category].push(current?.data()?.category);
   return prev;
}, {});
```

Error:

```
The left-hand side of an 'in' expression must be a private identifier or of type 'any', 'string', 'number', or 'symbol'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally converted `current?.data()?.drinkName` to a boolean by adding `!` before it. Try wrapping the whole statement with parenthesis like so
`!(current?.data()?.drinkName in prev)`. This way the `!` negates the whole statement and not just the left part.

I would have also added a condition that checks whether `current?.data()?.drinkName` is null before checking if it exists in `prev`, because theoretically `prev` might contain `null`.

```
if (!(current?.data()?.drinkName) || !(current?.data()?.drinkName in prev))
```